# How can I get the authentication of WP login ?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently working on wordpress .As I am new to wordpress, I wanted to know how WP authenticate the user.
I search the code and at `wp-login.php` page i found that-

```
$user = wp_signon('', $secure_cookie);
```

this function returns  the authentication of user .
when i go to the definition of wp_signon I got these two functions-

```
// TODO do we deprecate the wp_authentication action?
    do_action_ref_array('wp_authenticate', array(&$credentials['user_login'], &$credentials['user_password']));
```

and

```
$user = wp_authenticate($credentials['user_login'], $credentials['user_password']);
```

But finally I never got the page OR code where actual authentication takes place ??and where the user password is encrypted and match with database??.

Please help,
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in wp-includes/user.php there is a function called "wp_authenticate_username_password" that does the actual authentication this function then calls "wp_check_password" within wp-includes/pluggable.php the username is essentially compared in plaintext to the database as you would expect in within the same file, hope this points you in the right direction.